# Unit Test Service using Junit 4

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4

I am trying to write Unit Test for Android Service using JUNIT4.
Following my service code:

```
class myService extends Service {

    // Binder given to clients
    private IBinder mBinder = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    }

    public int multiply(int x, int y){
        return (x*y);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

        public myService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call     public methods.
            return myService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

And My Unit test Code:

```
public class testServiceUlt {

@Rule
public final ServiceTestRule mServiceRule = new ServiceTestRule();

@Test
public void testWithBoundService() throws TimeoutException, InterruptedException {

    // Create the service Intent.
    Intent serviceIntent =
            new Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), myService.class);

    // Bind the service and grab a reference to the binder.
    IBinder binder = mServiceRule.bindService(serviceIntent);

    // Get the reference to the service, or you can call public methods on the binder directly.
    myService service = ((myService.LocalBinder) binder).getService();

    int val = service.multiply(80, 0);
    assertEquals("should be zero", 0, val);

    }

}
```

The problem is that the binder is Null and I got the following error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.xxx.xxx.xxx com.example.xxx.xxx.xxx$LocalBinder.getService()' on a null object reference

Can you please advice what is my problem?
P.S - I know how to do it using Junit3 with ServiceTestCase, but I would like to do with Junit4

Thanks,
Zachi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.
By mistake my AndroidManifest.xml file did not include the Service.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I declared the Service in the androidTest Manifest file, which isn't working for any reason.